# Running Kubernetes master and node on the same server (scheduling pods on Kubernetes master)

Tags: kubernetes

If you run taint command on Kubernetes master:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

it allows you to schedule pods.
So it acts as node and master.

I have tried to run 3 server cluster where all nodes have both roles. I didn't notice any issues from the first look.

Do you think nowadays this solution can be used to run small cluster for production service? If not, what are the real downsides? In which situations this setup fails comparing with standard setup?

Assume that etcd is running on all three servers.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard reason to run separate master nodes and worker nodes is to keep a busy workload from interfering with the cluster proper.

Say you have three nodes as proposed.  One winds up running a database; one runs a Web server; the third runs an asynchronous worker pod.  Suddenly you get a bunch of traffic into your system, the Rails application is using 100% CPU, the Sidekiq worker is cranking away at 100% CPU, the MySQL database is trying to handle some complicated joins and is both high CPU and also is using all of the available disk bandwidth.  You run `kubectl get pods`: which node is actually able to service these requests?  If your application triggers the Linux out-of-memory killer, can you guarantee that it won't kill `etcd` or `kubelet`, both of which are critical to the cluster working?

If this is running in a cloud environment, you can often get away with smaller (cheaper) nodes to be the masters.  (Kubernetes on its own doesn't need a huge amount of processing power, but it does need it to be reliably available.)

Comment: Thanks, that's wide enough answer. Let's say I'm using resources.limit to limit every pod's RAM and CPU and plenty of RAM on bare metal server, separate disk for app, wider, but sensible ulimit parameters for users (containers can use different users from Linux host perspective so they are isolated) and monitoring in place. Do we see any corruption possibilities, especially from k8s components perspective such as `etcd` and `kubelet`?

Comment: After using it for half a year, I haven't noticed any problems by living without nodes. I wouldn't classify this solution as problematic if you know how to limit your workloads. These are resources management and security questions which are fixable. I still agree that for big product, it makes sense to separate nodes in production and usually it doesn't cost more if speaking relatively/saves time.